# Keybinding according to mode

Tags: key-bindings, major-mode

I have done the following keybindings.  Although they work, `eval-last-sexp` is only relevant it lisp-interaction-mode, emacs-lisp-mode, and lisp-mode, whereas `eval-expression` is more relevant in non-lisp modes.

How can I adapt the two functions into a single function that distinguishes between list and non-lisp modes, setting the keybinding accordingly?

```
(defun ktrig-eval ()
  "Rapid keybinding triggering `C-x C-e'."
  (global-set-key (kbd "H-e") #'eval-last-sexp))

(defun ktrig-evalx ()
  "Rapid keybinding triggering `M-:'."
  (global-set-key (kbd "H-a") #'eval-expression))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each mode comes with a key map which is active only when that mode is active and which overrides key bindings from the global key map. By adding your key bindings to the correct key map you can get the behavior you want. See [chapter 49.3 Customizing Key Bindings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html) of the Emacs manual. You can also read this manual inside of Emacs with `C-h i`. Everything you need to know is in there.

For example:

```lisp
(define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map (kbd "H-e") #'eval-last-sexp)
```

Comment: A small problem I have is that I want to have the same keybinding `H-e`.  That is, use `H-e` for `eval-last-sexp`, but use `eval-expression` for non-lisp modes.  For the latter I would not have a specific named mode.

Comment: Right, do you see where it says that local key maps override the global one? Define one key in the global map for non–lisp modes and then override it with a key binding in `emacs-lisp-mode-map`.

Comment: Like this `(global-set-key (kbd "H-a") #'eval-expression)` followed by `(define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map (kbd "H-e") #'eval-last-sexp)`.  I do not see that `global-set-key` allows any mode or non-mode associations.

Comment: Exactly like that, but they can use the same key.

Comment: Are `lisp-mode-map` and `emacs-lisp-mode-map` the only modes one can insert lisp code directly?

Comment: I wouldn’t want to be too definitive on that point; Emacs is huge. Just do it for the modes you personally use.

Comment: There is lisp-interaction-mode as well.